# How do you invert function parameters for lapply in R?

Tags: r, parameters, lapply

I've been wondering for awhile: in R, what is the recommendend way to invert function parameters for order-dependent functions to allow apply-style processing on a list of items?

For a simple example, say I have a list of numbers, and a single divisor.

```
numerator = list(5, 10, 15, 250)
denominator = 2
```

I want to divide each number by the divisor. I know I can easily use a numeric vector in this case:

```
as.numeric(numerator)/denominator
# [1]   2.5   5.0   7.5 125.0
```

But in the real world, the list may contain a more complex data structure, making a vector cast impossible. This is just a simple example. Instead, we could use lapply (or sapply) like this, to yield the same answer:

```
sapply(numerator, "/", denominator)
# [1]   2.5   5.0   7.5 125.0
```

So here's the question: What do you do if you want to flip the arguments to the function? As in, divide "denominator" by each number, instead of the other way around?  Usually to "/" you provide numerator, then denominator. But now I want to divide denominator by numerator, the "/" function can no longer be used with sapply (which requires the list item to be the first argument of the function).

I want this result:

```
denominator/as.numeric(numerator)
# [1] 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.1333333 0.0080000
```

The way I typically do this is to write a new function inverting the parameters:

```
inverse_divide = function(denominator, numerator) {
    return(numerator/denominator)
}
```

Now, it works:

```
sapply(numerator, inverse_divide, denominator)
# [1] 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.1333333 0.0080000
```

But this gets old. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `mapply`.  It can take corresponding elements from both the `vector` and `list` and divide `/`. In this case, there is only a single element for 'denominator', so it will be recycled.  If the length of the elements are the same in both 'numerator' and 'denominator', the corresponding elements are used as mentioned above.

```
 mapply(`/`, denominator, numerator)
 #[1] 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.1333333 0.0080000

 mapply(`/`, numerator, denominator)
#[1]   2.5   5.0   7.5 125.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be

```
sapply(numerator, function(x) denominator / x)
## [1] 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.1333333 0.0080000
```